# select an item in the CListCtrl on CEdit text change

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl, cedit

I am tasked to do a real-time search using a edit box. When the text in the edit box matches the item in clistctrl, it will be highlighted. What I really want to do is highlight the matched item in Clistctrl on cedit box change.

Answer (score 0):

The edit box send [WM_COMMAND EN_CHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761676(v=vs.85).aspx) every time when you enter a character. So add a ON_ handler for this Event and perform your search.

Comment: I am pretty new to mfc. Can you please show me a piece of code on how to do this? thanks in advance

Comment: The first step is to add a message handler for EN_CHANGE from the edit control. That is done with the IDE wizard, not by adding code. So start with a tutorial so you can learn how to add message handlers.